# Is there a way to add a new iframe in the current page DOM with a chrome extension

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to add a new iframe to the DOM of the current page within a contetn script.
I am getting a popup saying it is not allowed.

I would like to know if this is a permission issue (I did set all_frame: true). Or not possible at all.

In advance thanks.

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Comment: I will add my code but do you know if it is possible at all ?